# Ideal $I=(x^3,x^5)$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ . It is true that $I=(x^3)$ ?What about $I=(x^5)$?

Tags: ideals

Ideal $~I=(x^3,x^5)~$  in $~\mathbb Q[x]~$ . It is true that $~I=(x^3)~$ ?What about $~I=(x^5)~$ ?

**My work :** I was thinking to solve this with something like:

$~(x^3)(1+x^2)=x^3+x^5~$
and $~(1+x^2)\in \mathbb Q[x]~$

and for $~I=(x^5)\implies 
(x^5)*(1+1/x^2)=x^3+x^5~$
but $~1/x^2~$ is not always in $~\mathbb Q[x]~$, I think.

How close to the answer am I ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial ring $K[x]$, where $K$ is a field, is a principal ideal domain. Each nonzero ideal is generated by the small monic polynomial containing it (smallest in the sense of degree). The reason is that in $K[x]$ we have division with remainder.

In your case, $I=\langle x^3,x^5\rangle = \langle x^3\rangle$ with $x^5 = x^2\cdot x^3$.

Moreover, the ideal $\langle x^5 \rangle$ is contained in $\langle x^3\rangle$.

Comment: So if I=⟨3,x^3⟩  ?      @Wuestenfux

Comment: @ROSole: Since 3 is invertible, the ideal equals the whole ring.